# Python sort lists of tuples, and those lists happen to be dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new in Python I am trying to sort I saw some posts on stackoverflow but i was not able to get my headaround the problem

```
graph = {
'A': [('B', 9), ('C', 7)],
'B': [('A', 5), ('D', 8), ('E', 1)],
'E': [('B', 1), ('D', 2)],
'D': [('B', 8), ('E', 2), ('F', 7), ('C', 2), ('I', 5)],
'F': [('D', 7)],
'I': [('D', 5), ('G', 14)],
'G': [('I', 14), ('C', 13)],
'C': [('A', 7), ('D', 2), ('G', 13)]}

for key, value in sorted(graph.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
    print ("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

I want to sort this dictionary by value of each element
For Example First item becomes
'A': [('C', '7'), ('B', 9)],
'B': [('E', 1),('A', 5), ('D', 8)],
and so on

How can i do that
in python

Comment: Doesn't look like you want to sort the dictionary.

Comment: You want to sort lists of tuples, and those lists happen to be  dictionary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over the values and use `list.sort` to sort it in-place:

```
for v in graph.values():
    v.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
print(graph)
```

If you want a new dictionary, you could use `sorted` in a dict comprehension:

```
out = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x:x[1]) for k,v in graph.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'A': [('C', 7), ('B', 9)],
 'B': [('E', 1), ('A', 5), ('D', 8)],
 'E': [('B', 1), ('D', 2)],
 'D': [('E', 2), ('C', 2), ('I', 5), ('F', 7), ('B', 8)],
 'F': [('D', 7)],
 'I': [('D', 5), ('G', 14)],
 'G': [('C', 13), ('I', 14)],
 'C': [('D', 2), ('A', 7), ('G', 13)]}
```